# ServiceStack ORMLite - How to Select All to match the request DTO's properties automatically

Tags: request, servicestack, where-clause, dto, ormlite-servicestack

I have several ServiceStack ORMLite POCO, one is Company below.

```
    public class Company
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public int? companyNo { get; set; }
        public bool? active { get; set; }
    }
```

If two properties are valid in the following request: req.company="ABC Company", req.active=ture, and all other properties are null. Then it can return all records matching the two properties. The code may look like below:

```
    public object Get(Company req)
    {
        return Db.Select<Company>().Where<Company>(req);
    }
```

Does ServiceStack ORMLite have such a WHRER to auto-match the valid properties in the request DTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature in OrmLite, but it's available in [AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) where you just need to define the Request DTO you want to query, e.g:

```
[Route("/company/search")]
public class QueryCompany : IQuery<Company>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyNo { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}
```

With just the Request DTO, ServiceStack automatically creates the Service for you which you can query like any other Service.

### Enable AutoQuery

You can enable AutoQuery by registering the AutoQuery Feature, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { MaxLimit = 100 });
```

AutoQuery is available in the [ServiceStack.Server](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Server) NuGet package:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Server
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mythz. It works for me. My code is like below:

```
// ====== Model.cs ========
[Route("/company/search")]
public class QueryableCompany : QueryBase<Company>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyNo { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public int companyNo { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
}
// ====== Service.cs ========
public IAutoQuery AutoQuery { get; set; }

public object Get(QueryableCompanies dto)
{
    var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request.GetRequestParams());
    var r = AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q);
    return r.Results; 
}

// ====== Global.asax.cs ========
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //...
    Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { MaxLimit = 100 });
    //...
}
```

Then, I have two more questions based on the code above.

1) Since I have a lot of request DTOs, their code in Get(QueryableXXX dto) is all the same; How can I use a single generic Get() method to return all different types of DTO, like:

```
public object Get<T>(T dto) where T : IQuery
{
    var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request.GetRequestParams());
    return AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q).Results;
}
```

2) In the Company example above, class QueryableCompany seems so similar to class Company, can AutoQuery provide some Attributes to class Company's members, and avoid to create another similar QueryableCompany?

Comment: Can you ask new questions with a new question, as we can't add any answers to answers, just comments.